# Error int function python

Tags: python, function, int

I'm receving a error when I want to convert a str to int in python

My code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


link_cat = 'http://www.www.uol.com.br/'
r = requests.get(link)


soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")


for div in soup.find_all('a', {"class" : "last-page"}):
lp = div['href']



import re



regex = r"^.*\/([0-9]+)\/$"

#Define str
strlp = lp


matches = re.search(regex, strlp)



if matches:

for groupNum in range(0, len(matches.groups())):
    groupNum = groupNum + 1

valor_final = matches.group(groupNum)
valor_final = int(matches.group(groupNum))

print(valor_final)
type(valor_final)
```

Traceback:

```
$ ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-498cbd1c956a> in <module>()
     42 
     43 valor_final = matches.group(groupNum)
---> 44 valor_final = int(matches.group(groupNum))
     45 
     46 print(valor_final)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Fix your indents and things first, it's all wonky

Comment: Do you by any chance use Spyder/Anaconda/Canopy?

Comment: Your stack trace says the error is on line 44 but you only have 40 lines of code here. Please share the entire code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the issue you're facing, whether or not you're utilising iPython through Spyder or some other IDE. You've trampled `int` some time in the past and it's now lingering around leaving no obvious root of the error

Comment: Thank you all, was an indention error!